# package in requirements.txt, but not seen in docker

Tags: python, docker, redis, celery

I have valid requirements.txt file, but docker doesn't install one of packages listed in requirements

Docker version 18.09.2
python 3.7.3

requirements.txt

```
django==2.2.2
celery==4.2.1
selenium==3.141.0
BeautifulSoup4==4.7.1
redis==3.2.0
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV DJANGO_ENV dev
ENV DJANGO_ENV dev
COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r /code/requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
WORKDIR /code/
EXPOSE 8000
```

docker_compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.6.5
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "python /code/manage.py migrate --noinput && python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
  celery:
    build: .
    command: celery -A google_scraper worker -l info
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

actual error while I try to run celery:

`ImportError: Missing redis library (pip install redis)`

When I run bash for docker, and install it by manual pip3 install redis - it works fine, but still it doesn't solve problem of building it, I don't have idea where I make mistake.

Comment: when you `pip install redis` in  docker, which version is installed ?

Comment: 3.2.0 but I tried with different versions

Comment: Might not be the problem, but there's a typo in the filename `requirements.txt` above.

Comment: Yes mistake there not in project - I am repairing it

Comment: Are you sure the python-pip installed in the base image?

Comment: @CharlesXu Yes, it installs django, celery etc... only not this package

Answer (score 0):

I wonder how come Docker did not complain about a missing `/code` directory? Are you sure Docker have successfully built the image? If it did, please explain to me how the `COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt` worked? I checked, the `python:3.7` image does not have that directory in its root file-system...